# So Stack Exchange still likes to keep closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Stack Exchange sites have people who close questions for the different reasons. If the question is bad, it gets closed. Does it get deleted? If not, why not? You made the decision the question is not helpful and it doesn't make the internet a better place. So why is the question still around? Do you think it still has some value?

If you're keeping it to have examples of what constitutes a bad question, how long and how many questions are needed for this to happen?

Comment: Do you have a specific question in mind?

Comment: Being closed is not necessarily a permanent state for a question. Some can still be improved to be a good question which deserves to be reopened.

Answer (score 7):

It can take time for questions that get closed to get deleted - the delete vote privileges kick in at rep +10k, compared to +3k for close votes. At +10k, one can only vote to delete within 2 days of the question being asked (it is immediate for trusted users at +20k).

This difference is enough to explain why closed questions stay around for a while.

Some questions are duplicates and are closed as such - if the phrasing is different enough from the duplicate, it is worth keeping for SEO - is helps people find the question and its answers, even if they *are* duplicates.

> If you're keeping it to have examples of what constitutes a bad question, how long and how many questions are needed for this to happen?

SO doesn't work like this. It is a community. And sometimes questions are simply... forgotten... There are many closed questions that are in "limbo", waiting to be deleted but since no one is looking at them they don't.

Comment: +1 for Limbo (2 more.)